# How to add ssh key in git bash?

Tags: ssh

To add key in Gitbash Make sure to use to enable ssh agent first.

### eval $(ssh-agent -s)

[enter image description here][1]
Now you can add ssh key in git bash using below command.

if you are doing it in windows Git Bash.

### ssh-add /c/keyname

How to check if the key is added.

### ssh-add -L

you should see the ssh key added here .

Answer (score 5):

Below are the steps:

1. Open Git Bash and run below command on command prompt to generate public-private key pair   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@gmail.com"`
2. When you are prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key," press Enter. This accepts the default file location.

   > Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):[Press enter]
3. At the prompt, type a secure passphrase. You can press enter if you want to leave it blank but its not recommended.

   > Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
   > Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
4. Go to `/c/Users/username/.ssh/` folder and open `id_rsa.pub` file and copy entire contents of it.
5. Finally, go to `Github -> Settings -> SSH And GPG keys -> Click New RSA (Green Button`). Give some meaningful title to the key and paste the public key copied in step 4 above. Now click on Add SSH Key button.

Congrats, you have added public key to github successfully and now you can use gitbash to access github repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, I take a look from git GUI (in Windows). There is a menu about SSL (or SSH) and you can view the imported key.

Comment: Thanks , It is more with gitbash ,generally what happens ignore using forward slash while addind ssh key to this.